# How to read from multiple multiplexers (CD74HC4067) with a library

Tags: midi, multiplexer

I need to read alot of buttons and analog inputs for my project (60 buttons 15 faders) and there fore need to use multiplexers. But most mux libraries seems to only support one mux, am i wrong?

Comment: It seems to me a library is a bit overkill for that IC, since you have 4 pins to define which input pin/channel will be used. Seems to me to send 4 digital writes to define the channel, an one analog read for getting the signal. So since you do not a library, you can control them all the way you want.

Comment: Which library? You should be able to use multuple instances, and there are libraries that have support for cascaded muxes.